# How to store files in folder by giving sequential number

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am storing images (*.bmp) files in a folder and giving file names as a sequential numbers (i.e. 1, 2, 3 and so on). So, how to identify which was the last file name stored in the directory. So that when my application, when it starts next time it starts storing from the next consecutive number and does not overwrite any file. I am developing the application in C++/MFC.

Comment: What do you have so far? Most people are more willing to help if they have something they can base their answer on.

Comment: Can timestamps be used, or must it be the sequential numbers?

Comment: Read the directory, count the numbers, and add one.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Are you insane??? What if there are tons of files??

Comment: @ST3: The only other option is to store the latest number somewhere and keep it in sync at all times, then you can simply read that value when needed.  But then you risk failure if you are out of sync.  Iterating the actual files is more accurate, albeit more overhead, but it is a one time hit at startup.  You can thread it so your UI is not blocked, and you can use other tricks to speed it up, like reading the file system directly instead of using `FindFirstFile()`, etc.

Comment: @ST3: If the folder has so many "tons" of files in it that the program can't even read the directory once, what good is it going to be to a user?

Comment: @ljacqu: Currently I am using system command "dir /B /O:DN *.bmp > C:\\FileNames.txt" which will write down all file names in any directory to a text file. Then I just read that text file and take the last file name written in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows registry lets you save data like this when your program closes and retrieve the data the next time the program runs. In MFC:

```
AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString(...);
```